# Capitalization of Person names in programming

Tags: rules, capitalization

Is anyone aware of some code/rules on how to capitalize the names of people correctly?

- John Smith
- Johan van Rensburg
- Derrick von Gogh
- Ruby de La Fuente
- Peter Maclaurin
- Garry McDonald

(these may not be correct, just some sample names and how the capitalization could be/work)

This seems like a losing battle...

If anyone has some code or rules on when and how to capitalize names, let me know.

Comment: My bet is on "impossible".

Comment: Remember, Ian McDonald (from Scotland) has a different capitalization from Ian Mcdonald (from Ireland).

Comment: @naysayers, everything is possible.

Comment: When in doubt, ALL CAPS.

Comment: @Amissico: Actually, no, it isn't. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Actually, it is..."Sometimes, close enough is good enough." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263911(VS.85).aspx. From the answers provided, I am sure Albert will find a way.

Comment: I'm wondering how it'd be to have a suggestion pop-up when they onblur after entering their last name. If it's all lower case perhaps, they can then choose to correct it. If it's complex, show some options, when they click submit, that is the end of the story...

Comment: Awareness in application development, anywhere a surname, or any part of their name is presented outward is pretty important. Our most basic rule is simply, "believe the user, on what the correct spelling is, for their own name." Never change mixed casing unless it's done, as I call it, "legal style," ALL CAPS. Or "uni style," all lowercase. Anything other than those two exceptions, and you've literally spelled their name wrong. We have 2 fields in a table for this. users.search_name : ALL UPPERCASE, "USER MCCLURE"; users.display_name: Presented exactly the same as given, "User McClure"

Comment: @Albert Unfortunately, someone closed the question. I have posted an answer in a seperate thread. You can find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77575179/6676101) or by searching for "How do I automatically capitalize a person's name?" Even if the original poster (OP) no longer wants an answer after 14 years, someone else is likely to ask the same question and the answer will still be valid.

Answer (score 20):

The only sensible way to handle it, in my opinion, is to let the users tell you how their name should be capitalized.  Any automatic scheme is going to annoy someone.

Answer (score 7):

Just tell them you're OLD SCHOOL.  That makes it simple and 100% correct:

```
- JOHN SMITH
- JOHAN VAN RENSBURG
- DERRICK VON GOGH
- RUBY DE LA FUENTE
- PETER MACLAURIN
- GARRY MCDONALD
```

The same logic also helps with many i18n problems.

Comment: Marc Harisson - agree. people tend to get annoyed when you get their names wrong ...

Comment: this is not quite viable in an application though. Imagine your outlook contacts were all UPPER CASE, I think I'd go deaf :\ It could be usefull in some instances though, not this one.

Comment: @Albert - Oh, I wish people would stop with that allcaps=loud shouting equality. They're letters like all else. Nothing special about them if they're all caps.

Comment: I tell them I'm so old school I don't even use computers. Thus the whole programming problem is circumvented.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [this implementation in Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20090223120300/http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2010) which is based on [this algorithm](http://www.johncardinal.com/tmgutil/capitalizenames.htm). The basic idea is convert the name to title case then check the name against a giant look-up table of exceptions.

But really what Jonathan Leffler said is spot on: unless you have some requirement to convert pre-existing unformatted data, automated capitalization is going to do something wrong (especially as capitalization rules vary across language divides, cultural divides, name changes that result from emigration or people just preferring to capitalize their name in some particular fashion).

Comment: Without going through the list of exceptions associated with that algorithm, I'd bet on it's being quite incomplete with regards to polish names starting with 'Mac'.

Answer (score 1):

I kept a lookup of names that needed special handling. When a case-insensitive match was found, I used the lookup value. This did not resolve people who used case that did not match the "accepted" capitalization. It allowed me/user to add names as needed. I can't find my code, but I did get the surnames from http://www.census.gov/.

Comment: the version of eth surnames i got from census.gov was all in uppercase.. so it was useless