# how do i bring capital letters when i am typing a name in a codeigniter view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 name fields in a codeigniter view. When I type in the name in these 3 fields, I want the first letter of the name to be capital letter.

How do I do this?

```
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'last_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter your last name','value'=>set_value('last_name')])?>
```

I need first letter of my name in capital letters. This needs to be inserted in to database table field with the same.

Comment: try to use `ucwords()` before adding in `database`

Comment: where do I use ucwords()  ?

Comment: before inserting in db in model

Comment: but i need the first letter of name to come in capital letters in my view as well

Comment: there is a reason why this isn't done. what if the users last name is `von Buren`? see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580554/proper-capitalization-of-surnames-in-php

Comment: I have some text boxes in my view like this:
<?=form_input(['name'=>'last_name','type'=>'text','style'=>'text-transform:capitalize','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter your last name','value'=>set_value('last_name')])?>
i have a database table 'userlogin' which has a field  'last_name'
when I am entering the value in the last_name field, i want autofill function in it with all the values from 'last_name' field in database. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

To show in view Please Use CSS `text-transform` to do this

```html
<input type='text' name='f_name' style='text-transform:capitalize'>
<br>
<input type='text' name='l_name'>
```

You can see here `f_name` will start with a capital letter and `l_name` will not

> After submitting your form you must need to use `ucword()` in controller or Model before inserting in DB

Controller:

```
$fname = ucword($this->input->post('f_name'));
$lname = ucword($this->input->post('l_name'));
```

then send it to Model to save it

Comment: will this also post with the first letter capitalized? (not op, just curious)

Comment: No, it will not post, OP, need to use `ucwords()` in the controller as i mentioned in above comment

Comment: i've just checked. if you have caps lock off, and you type `asd` even though it looks like `Asd` it will post as `asd`. This solution would have to be used in conjunction with ucwords.

Comment: code updated. Kindly accept the answer if it is worked

Comment: please accept the answer, and ask your question as new question in SO