# How do I automatically capitalize a person's name?

Tags: capitalization

How do I automatically capitalize a person's name?

Suppose that there is a cellphone app where people sign-up for volunteer work opportunities and/or paid jobs.

We wish to capitalize names of volunteers.

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| `Noodlum Leumas` | `Noodlum Leumas` |
| `NoOdLuM LeUmAs` | `Noodlum Leumas` |
| `noodlum leumas` | `Noodlum Leumas` |
| `nOODLUM lEUMAS` | `Noodlum Leumas` |

---

I have filed job applications with multiple multi-billion dollar corporations such that the corporation cellphone app displayed an error message complaining that I typed my name in all-caps or all-lower case letters.

In order to improve the end-user's experience (for better UX design) we can fix the capitalization on their name for them.

Comment: The short answer is that you generally _don't_ do this. You take it how it's entered. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466706/capitalization-of-person-names-in-programming for reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalization of Person names in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466706/capitalization-of-person-names-in-programming)

Answer (score -5):

The following is a partial solution, but not the best answer.

Someone else is sure to post an even better answer and receive more upvotes.

For instance, `McDonald` and `MkKormic` are unlikely to be capitalized correctly.

| INPUT | CORRECT OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| `mcdonald` | `McDonald` |
| `MKCORMIC` | `MkCormic` |
| `noodlum leumas` | `Noodlum Leumas` |
| `nOODLUM lEUMAS` | `Noodlum Leumas` |

```python
def auto_captialize(istring:str) -> str:
    """
        input parameter namd `istring` is input string
    """
    # `sepwrds` is `seperated words`
    iwords = istring.split()
    
    owords = type(iwords)
    
    for iword in iwords:
        ileft_side  = iword[0]
        iright_side = iword[1:] 
        
        # convert left side of the word into all
        # uppercase letters
        oleft_side  = ileft_side.upper()
        
        oright_side = iright_side.lower()
        
        oword = oleft_side + oright_side
        
        # Append a string to the container of output words
        # insert instance of string class into somthing like List of strings
        owords.append(oword)
        
    ostring = " ".join(owords)
    # ostring ...... is ...... `output string`
    return ostring
    
    
######################################

inames = [
    "Noodlum Leumas",
    "NoOdLuM LeUmAs",
    "noodlum leumas",
    "nOODLUM lEUMAS",
]

for iname in inames:
   oname = auto_captialize(iname)
   print(oname)
```

Comment: Leaving aside concerns of code quality, the functional issues you've _already_ identified and whether it even actually runs (no), you've basically just rewritten [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title).